# Is there a “breadth-first” search option available in os.walk() or equivalent Python function?

Tags: python

Example directory tree:

```
     root
     /|\
    / | \
   /  |  \
  A   B   C
     /     \
    /       \
   D         E
              \
               \
                F
                 \
                  \
                   G
```

os.walk() will traverse this directory tree using the depth-first search algorithm. For example, os.walk() will process this tree in this order: root, A, B, D, C, E, F, G. os.walk() doesn't seem to provide an option for a breadth-first search. If this option were available, it would process this tree in this order instead: root, A, B, C, D, E, F, G. In my application, I need to do the reverse search. However, os.walk(tree, topdown = False) yields: A, D, B, G, F, E, C, root. On the contrary, the breadth-first search in reverse would yield: G, F, E, D, C, B, A, root.

I've had to create my own solution which is below:

```
def reversewalk(path):
    dirlist = {}
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        depth = dirName.count(os.path.sep)
        dirlist[os.path.abspath(dirName)] = (depth, dirName, subdirList, fileList)
    return sorted(dirlist.items(), key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
```

My question is: Is there a "breadth-first" search option available in os.walk() or equivalent Python function? Follow up question is: If not, is there a better solution than the one I've presented?

Comment: If your function works, this is more appropriate for code review.

Comment: I think you want to play with `topdown=False` option.

Comment: As I said in the posting above, the topdown=False option does not work the way I need it to work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I believe `topdown=False` is still a variant of DFS

Comment: @JohnasCukier http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511456-breadth-first-file-iterator/

Comment: Each time I wanted to implement a breadth first tree walking in Python, a double ended queue (either a `deque` object or a standard list in which you append at beginning and end) provided a solution. I'm pretty sure it can help here too.

Comment: Yes, it is DFS in reverse. I need BFS in reverse.

Comment: The issue with reverse folder traversal from the deepest node is that you actually have to read in the whole structure and that's why `os.walk()` does not provide it. I'd write a simple weighted tree structure and fill it with `os.walk()`. Then one can scan it in any direction and from any node depth needed...

Comment: @chisz Thanks! I'll take a look. Instead of a code review (I know it works), I'm looking for a built-in option or a better solution than what I have posted. If these don't exist, I'll take your advice and just use what I have. Thanks again.

Comment: @zwer thanks. I think I've done that in my example code. If you have an implementation that you can share, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @chrisz I tried the code you referenced. It works, but it doesn't seem to have a BFS in reverse option. I need to process the leaves first. Thanks though. I'll look into it further.

Comment: @JohnasCukier - Instead of reinventing the wheel, there is a useful [`anytree`](http://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package that can do exactly what you need - an `os.walk()` traversal to fill the tree and a simple `reversed(anytree.LevelOrderIter(your_tree))` to iterate it should do the trick. It might be a bit of an overkill over your approach, tho.

Comment: @zwer anytree looks interesting. I think it's a bit heavy for what I need though.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is from [an ActiveState article](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511456-breadth-first-file-iterator/) I read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

# -------------------------------------------
def breadthFirstFileScan( root ) :
    dirs = [root]
    # while we has dirs to scan
    while len(dirs) :
        nextDirs = []
        for parent in dirs :
            # scan each dir
            for f in os.listdir( parent ) :
                # if there is a dir, then save for next ittr
                # if it  is a file then yield it (we'll return later)
                ff = os.path.join( parent, f )
                if os.path.isdir( ff ) :
                    nextDirs.append( ff )
                else :
                    yield ff
        # once we've done all the current dirs then
        # we set up the next itter as the child dirs 
        # from the current itter.
        dirs = nextDirs

# -------------------------------------------
# an example func that just outputs the files.
def walkbf( path ) :
    for f in breadthFirstFileScan( path ) :
        print f

# ============================================
# as a demo we'll just start from where we 
# were called from.
walkbf( os.getcwd() )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a bit more terse and more closely mimics os.walk()'s functionality. (It's interesting this works because of Python's implicit handling of lexicographic sorting of tuples.)

```
def rbf_walk(path):
    dirlist = ((dirpath.count(os.path.sep), dirpath, dirnames, filenames) for
        dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path, topdown = False))
    for entry in sorted(dirlist, reverse = True):
        yield entry[1:]
```

Comment: There's not much point making this a generator: `sorted()` will force evaluation of `dirlist` in its entirely so the whole `os.walk()` call has to complete before it can `yield` the first item. You might as well just return the result of `sorted()` directly.

And as such, this is fine if you either have a small tree or don't care about latency.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets here looking for breadth first search because it is faster for their particular application, here is a solution that is easily readable, uses generators and recursion, and has the speed benefits of BFS.

```
def bfs_walk(directories):
    listdirs = [os.listdir(d) for d in directories]
    files    = [[fn for fn in listdir if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir,fn))] for listdir, dir in zip(listdirs, directories)]
    dirs     = [[dn for dn in listdir if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir,dn))]  for listdir, dir in zip(listdirs, directories)]

    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in zip(directories, dirs, files):
        yield dirname, dirnames, filenames

    directories = sum([list(map(lambda child: os.path.join(parent, child), children)) for parent, children in zip(directories, dirs)], [])
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in bfs_walk(directories):
        yield dirname, dirnames, filenames
```

However, be warned that recursion is severely limited in python : you won't be able to go very deep with this method.